# Unbound version of bindAttr in emberjs handlebars template

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

In cases where binding isn't needed, we can use `{{unbound someProperty}}`, but is there a way to achieve the same effect with tag attributes? As I understand it, our only option is `bindAttr` such as:

```
<img {{bindAttr src="thumbpath"}} />
```

Assuming 100+ images on the screen, and a somewhat frequent re-rendering (of the entire layout- not just the images), would there be any performance benefit in an unbound version?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Because Ember doesn't need to track unbound values, you can actually just do this:

```
<img src="{{unbound thumbpath}}" />
```

And yes, there are performance benefits to using unbound values.

Comment: But not that much performance benefit, so use it carefully. http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#method_unbound